# How to prevent automatic redirection on upload with plupload?

Tags: javascript, plupload

I'm using plupload to allow users to upload their own content to my website. The idea is it uploads to a page and while it's uploading, they can set the title and related information, and when it's done they can save it and then the form will submit with the content to the back-end express server.

Though right now, plupload will post to the URL when it finishes uploading, giving the user no time to edit the fields or have a choice of clicking the save button.

How would I stop it from doing this, so the user can save and let it post manually, with the content and the rest of the field's data?

I've already tried setting plupload's 'url' property to nothing, but that does nothing, and it still posts. Express then sees no form data and no files/content at all.

This is my uploader:

```js
const uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes: 'html5,html4',
    browse_button: 'uploader',
    url: '#',
    filters : {
        max_file_size : '100mb',
        mime_types: [
            { title: 'Video files', extensions: 'mp4' }
        ]
    },
    init: {
        PostInit: () => {},
        FilesAdded: (up, files) => {
            uploader.start();
        },

        UploadProgress: (up, file) => {
            $('#file-progress').attr('value', file.percent);
        },

        UploadComplete: (up, files) => {
            $('#submit-button').show();
        },

        Error: (up, err) => {
            alert(`${err.code}: ${err.message}`);
        }
    }
});

uploader.init();
```

All I need is to be able to prevent it from completing, so when the user's ready they can click the save button to finish it. Though this isn't possible with my skill level, as I haven't been able to work it out.